# border-radius on table in html/css

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like a rounded border on my table's outer border. However, it does not appear that anything that I am trying is working. Any advise would be appreciated. What is perhaps more odd is that the code seems to work when I 'run' in stackoverflow, but does not work on my actual source code. I'm not sure if that is because I'm using Hugo as a platform? All of my other border-radius functions seem to work...

RELEVANT CODE

```css
.table-bor {
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: $theme;
  padding: 50px 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* not relevant */
.title-borrow {
  text-align: right;
  color: $theme;
  font-size: 30pt;
 }
 
 /* I HAVE ALSO TRIED THE FOLLOWING BUT IT DID NOT WORK */
td:first-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

th:last-of-type {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

tr:last-of-type td:first-of-type {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

tr:last-of-type td:last-of-type {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

/* AND IN THE ACTUAL HTML CODE, I HAVE TRIED THE FOLLOWING INDIVIDUALLY */
<table style="border-radius: 10px !important">
<table style="border-radius: 10px">

/* in first tr & th */ 
<tr style="border-top-left-radius: 10px">
<th style="border-top-left-radius: 10px">
```

```html
<table class="table-bor">
        <tr>
          <th class="title-borrow">Test</th>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="calc-input">Amount of the loan ($):</td>
          <td><input id="amount" placeholder="$300 - $2,500" onclick="calculate(this);"></td>
        </tr>
<!-- ... -->
         </table>
```

Comment: check in your browser console if the css are applied. Your problem isn't reproducible because your code is correct and works fine

Comment: what is this "border-color: $theme;" have you checked variable $theme have valid color code

Comment: @Asif I'm technically using SCSS, so the theme color is the color used throughout the website as a variable (so that I don't have to type in everything the hex code).

Comment: @Sfili_81 , when you say check your browser console, what do you mean? I'm running the code locally, so any changes I make should populate? I've also tried checking on Chrome & Safari. Both do not take the changes. What a bummer.

Comment: clicking F12 on your browser you see the browser console

Answer (score 0):

Check in your browsers inspector to see if something is overriding the style. As well your inspector should be able to show all of the css attributes being applied to any element so you can see what elements are actually being applied.